# Android 7 проблемы с локализацией

Tags: android

Android приложение поддерживает два языка, английский и французский. В зависимости от определённых условий приложение будет запущенно либо на английском либо на французском

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "fr");
```

код класса LocaleHelper

```
public class LocaleHelper {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, final String language) {
    String tmpLang = language;
    if (language.length() > 2) {
        tmpLang = language.substring(0, 2);
    }
    persist(context, tmpLang);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, tmpLang);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, tmpLang);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}

public static void clearPersist(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.remove(SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
    editor.apply();
}}
```

В activity я делаю

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
```

На android6 и ниже всё работает нормально, а на android7 и выше приложение запущенное на французском

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "fr");
```

локализовано частично, т.е часть текста на французском а часть на английском.

P.S
Title из toolbar локализован правильно

Comment: А вы попробуйте делать `setLocale` в классе `Application` в `onCreate`. Если нет такого класса у вас, создайте, укажите в манифесте приложения.
Я в этом классе задаю `Locale` и всё норм.

Comment: спасибо за идею

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в подгрузке не правильного context. часть кода инициализируется с помощью  Dagger , при инициализации подгружался application context в котором язык был по умолчанию